# the use of the phrase 'interested for his school to create'

Tags: grammaticality

I ran across a sentence. I don't understand the usage in it.
Can the phrase 'for + noun + to-infinitive' follow 'interested'?
The sentence is:

> But, there were not enough students interested for his school to create a course.

Comment: You're parsing the sentence slightly incorrectly.  It's not really one phrase that goes "interested for *noun* to *verb*".  Think of the sentence this way:  There were not enough students **who were** interested / for his school **to be willing** to create a course."

Comment: Thanks, stangdon. The sentence is from the news, New York Times.

Comment: Expanding on @standon's response: the *for* clause is the complement of *interest* expressing how much lack of interest there was--for instance, we might also say "There wasn't enough interest for the school to create a course".

Answer (score 1):

There's a cliché which follows the same pattern.   What is it?   That's for me to know and for you to find out.

No, that's not an evasion.   That's the cliché.   This is the pattern:

> for me to know 
>   for you to find out 
>   for the school to create a course

The preposition "for" can license an object and a to-infinitive object complement.

Yes, such a prepositional phrase can follow the participle "interested".   In your example, however, it doesn't modify that one word directly.   The same sentiment could be expressed with a slightly different (and, to my eye, slightly more natural) word order:

> . . . enough interested students for his school to create a course.

The prepositional phrase "for his school to create a course" modifies the entire noun phrase "enough students interested", regardless of whether "interested" is placed before or after "students".